# Laravel relationLoaded() loads relation

Tags: php, laravel

When using `relationLoaded(string)` together with `when(bool, fn)`, it appears to actually load a relation (`hasMany()`).

API call:

```
return [
    'rels_before' => $this->getRelations(),
    'rank' => $this->when($this->relationLoaded('ranks'), $this->ranks->first()),
    'rels_after' => $this->getRelations(),
];
```

API Response:

```
"rels_before": [],
"rels_after": {
    "ranks": [
        {
            "id": 22,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": "2018-03-23 19:54:12",
            "user_id": 22,
            "season_id": 1,
            "points": 2124
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, checking my MySQL log, I see that the *ranks* query is fired. Why is it being fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, one is supposed to use `whenLoaded()` instead. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question by chance. I assume you've already solved it, but for future reference:

You're assumption isn't correct. Using `relationLoaded()` doesn't load the relation itself. It's because you're not wrapping your desired value in a closure. Your code should be:

```
'rank' => $this->when($this->relationLoaded('ranks'), function () {
    return $this->ranks->first();
}),
```

In your case `first()` always gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. The right Laravel `relationLoaded()` is just showing true or false. It checks if the model is loaded the relation. Eg.

```
$user = User::first();

$user->relationLoaded('image'); // False

$user = User::with(['image'])->first();

$user->relationLoaded('image'); // True
```